# Monitoring Database Row Count Growth

Tags: database

Is there a tool that monitors database table row count growth over time?

I have a database with 5000+ tables that I would like to monitor row count growth on over time.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy with [nagios plugins](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/MySQL/check_mysql_count/details), and you can also get good results with [ganglia and gmetric](http://codeinthehole.com/archives/8-Monitoring-MySQL-with-Ganglia-and-gmetric.html) although you'll have to modify the script to execute the query you want.

Comment: Cool. that sounds like it would work. We use HostMon here, so I guess I can just do it there. I just don't want it to add 5,000 new entries in the HostMon interface, and I would like it to capture historical data.

Comment: +1 for Ganglia - here's a simple plugin http://codeinthehole.com/archives/8-Monitoring-MySQL-with-Ganglia-and-gmetric.html